# category naming convention in objC

Tags: objective-c, header-files, categories

studying some sample code from an iOS programming course (cs193p fall2010) i came across
the sbjson framework which extends NSObject etc. by a category named SBJSON.
but in the +header "NSObject+SBJSON.h" it reads as:

```
@interface NSObject (NSObject_SBJSON)
```

where does the magic mapping of NSObject_SBJSON to SBJSON come from?
i noticed xcode accepting any string before the underline !?

but nowhere found a hint on that.

thanx
 klaus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't really a mapping, per se.  An Objective-C category is used to add additional methods to an existing class, without needing direct access to that class's corresponding implementation file/details.  So when you declare something like:

```
@interface NSObject (NSObject_SBJSON)
```

You are saying that your category adds methods to the `NSObject` class (and any class derived from it).  The "NSObject_SBJSON" part in parenthesis is not really significant, and can be anything you like (so long as it doesn't collide with the name of anyone else's category for that object type).  It does not even need to include "NSObject", so having `@interface NSObject (SBJSON)` would be equally valid.

Comment: So if one in a category implements two methods, should make an unique category or two separated ones?

Answer (score 2):

Categories are not named in the sense that your code will refer to them by name like a Protocol. The category name in this case is Xcode's (poor) translation of the file name `NSObject+SBJSON.h` to a category name; for some reason Xcode or Objective-C's compiler doesn't want the `+` in the category name.

The only time the category name is used is to match interface and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSObject+SBJSON.h` has been changed/solved in Xcode 4.2